# Cannot Upload Media, neither can I see the grid view in my WordPress website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a custom theme for my website, and I am unable to see media in **grid-view**, although I can see the images in **list-view**.

Secondly, whenever I upload a new image, I get the following three errors:

[image: these are the three errors I get every time I upload new image]

ERROR 1:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' not found or invalid function name

ERROR 2:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

ERROR 3:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

Comment: seems like WP's bug, did u try updating wordpress or download new wordpress pack ? [**here**](https://wordpress.org/download/)

Comment: My WordPress is latest version, and there's no update on it. I have 4.6 downloaded. Don't know what's the issue...

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in the past.  Try this out, you can put this in your functions.php

```
function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
$gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
$editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors',     'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried adding this into my functions.php file, but still the grid keeps on 'loading' forever! It shows nothing, and I tried every possible thing there is to debug it, but can't. I disabled and then enabled all plugins, I installed WordPress files manually, I also tried changing my browser every time I saw this issue, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Only thing that comes up my mind now is checking some of the php.ini values like max_upload_size / max_vars / execution time and so on.. maybe also try to upload your site to a linux server and see if things work better there..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple things to check:

• There might be an extra return or two after the last `?>` in a PHP file

• Turn off plugins 1 by one and see if that fixes it (you then know where the problem lies)

• If that doesn't work look at the functions.php in both themes

• If that doesn't work try deleting the last `?>`